# $watch is triggered directly after init, why?

Tags: angularjs

Why does [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) trigger directly after page load and how can I prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/dcSRu/2/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // Init scope vars
    $scope.data_copy = {};

    // If data_copy changes...
    $scope.$watch("data_copy", function(newValue, oldValue) {

        alert("$watch triggered!");

    }, true);
}
```

Comment: This is also the case if you had a controller or directive which was initiated some time after page load.

Answer (score 49):

On first run both values (`newValue` and `oldValue`) are equal, so you may easily escape it by checking for equality:

```
$scope.$watch("data_copy", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue === oldValue){
    return;
  }
  alert("$watch triggered!");
});
```

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oUDLJzempHkAsAOeXuWQ?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Ahh, thanks! But can I really compare the two objects with ===, shouldn't I use something like underscore's _.isEqual(newValue, oldValue) ?

Comment: Probably, but I do already use underscore so I used that instead and it worked great.

Comment: @tidelipop Why you need _.isEqual, for $watch init, newValue oldValue will be the same.

What's the initial value in your case ?

Comment: Why does `$watch` even fire if `newValue === oldValue`? `$watch` is specifically designed to fire when those are NOT equal.

Comment: @poshest +1 - yes why is any of this necessary?

Comment: @poshest, on first change `oldValue==undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap $watch function into angular ready function.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() 
{ 
  $scope.$watch("data_copy", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    alert("$watch triggered!");
  }, true);
})
```

When angular loads page. It changes values and $watch is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There already have a very nice discussion in here:

[How do I ignore the initial load when watching model changes in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947771/how-do-i-ignore-the-initial-load-when-watching-model-changes-in-angularjs)

> $scope.$watch('fieldcontainer', function (new_fieldcontainer, old_fieldcontainer) {
>
> if (typeof old_fieldcontainer === 'undefined') return;
>
> // Other code for handling changed object here.
>
> });