# angular scope.$watch triggered twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

html template:

```
<button class=""  ng-click="item_popup.toggle()"/>
```

inside one directive:

```
app.directive('itemPopup', ['$sce', '$timeout', function($sce, $timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/'),
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

    toggle = function(){
        item.toggle = scope.items.checked == 0 ? 1 : 0
    }
}]);
```

and app:

```
app.directive('item', ['$filter','$timeout', function($filter,$timeout){
        scope.$watch('item.toggle', function(newValue,oldValue){
            if(newValue!=undefined && oldValue!=undefined && oldValue != newValue){
                // Do something 
            }
      });
}]);
```

the issue here is that each time toggle function is called, scope.$watch is triggered twice.

i tried to check some other answers, like:

[Angular expressions in $watch trigger twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942930/angular-expressions-in-watch-trigger-twice)

[$rootScope.$watch triggered twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356554/rootscope-watch-triggered-twice)

but non of them gives the answer.

Comment: How is the directive being used in the HTML template?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added html template code

Comment: Both the `item-popup` directive and `item` directive are incomplete. And there is no example of how either directive is used. It is normal for watches to be called multiple times per digest cycle if the model propagates changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough information to reproduce the problem.