# AngularJS $watch, wait variable declaration to trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below code :

variable declaration :

```
$scope.updateUploadView = 
{
  ready:{
    inview:false,
    text: "starting"
  },
  uploading:{
    inview:false,
    text: "uploading"
  },
  done:{
    inview:false,
    text: "done !"
  }
};
```

$watch :

```
angular.forEach($scope.updateUploadView, function(element, key) {
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return element;
  }, function() {
   // do stuff
  });
},true);
});
```

The problem here is that i want to ignore $watch to trigger on the undefined property because it cause the view to change 3 times on the start of the application. Is there any possibility to wait the variable declaration ?

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/2200/

Comment: throw that bunch of code into angular.element(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: already tried, still triggers 3 times :(

Comment: too little information is know about your controller/parent controller/template(s) structure. It's really hard to guess what can possibly affect this. But you have said it has triggered 3 times. that should tell you something! 3 controllers? 3 views? 3 objects? think along those lines. I don't know what else to suggest, find the point where everything is ready before applying watcher

Comment: i linked a jsfiddle, it'll be easier for you to understand

Comment: you probably simplified the fiddle example, it seems to be working perfectly fine

Comment: The fact is it console.log() every key onstart and i want it to do nothing. Just wait for $scope.myvar to be update so it should trigger just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for undefined in your watch function.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return element;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(!angular.isDefined(newValue) && angular.isDefined(oldValue)) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Well i was sure it would work but strangly it enter in the condition

Comment: Then they must be defined. Check the newValue and oldValue, what are they?

Comment: I don't use them ( maybe i'm using totally the wrong method i'm pretty new to angular ) i put a link to a jsfiddle if you want to try it'll be easier for you.

Comment: It appears to be working correctly, and since your data is present before you created the $watch, you don't even need to check for undefined as I suggested.
It's firing the $watch once for each of the 3 watches you created.
If this isn't what you're looking for, try using angular.equals() (see updated answer)

Comment: actually, that doesn't work as I expected it to.
Check out this post here for suggestions on how to skip the initial $watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947771/how-do-i-ignore-the-initial-load-when-watching-model-changes-in-angularjs

Comment: Thank you so much you made my night !