# $digest soon after $watch definition triggers "$apply already in progress..." error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am an angular-noob and I am trying to understand why the following triggers the "$apply is already in progress ..."  error.

Here is the code (and its really almost straight from the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
        scope.name = 'misko';
        scope.counter = 0;
        //A
        scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.count++;
        });
        //B
        scope.$digest();
    }]);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MainController">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLny2faq/5/

I get the in-famous "$apply already in progress" error but why is that ?

I would like to know why the digest cycle triggers without even being called ?

In other words, I am merely declaring watch listeners (@comment A) and triggering them by calling $digest() (@comment B) . But it seems like its somehow being called sooner and errors out when I explicitly called $digest(). Why is this so ?

Please advise.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Why are you trying to call scope.$digest()? The $watch is already triggered because you set the name variable. In general you only need to call $digest/$apply outside the angular framework, e.g. in unit testing.

Comment: @dz210 this code is almost straight from the documentation really .. but isn't the name variable really being set before $watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name variable is set before the watch yes, but all watches get called once on initialization:

[Per Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.

^ Can be taken care of [via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915585/771928):

```
$scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    // will only run if the value changes, on initial load the newvalue = oldvalue so it won't run this code.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to call $digest, you can use

```
$timeout(function(){
    scope.$digest();
}, 0);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/5pzd15z1/2/)