# AngularJS $watch strange behavior during controller initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('Demo', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  function notify(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('%s => %s', oldValue, newValue);
  }

  $scope.$watch('collection.length', notify);
  $scope.$watch('my', notify);

  $scope.collection = [];  
  $scope.my = 'hello';
});
```

`$watch` fires initially. And this code snippet will output:

```
0 => 0
hello => hello
```

Is it correct behavior? Of course I could check values for for equality, but what reasons for such as behaviour?

P.S. You could try this sample online: http://jsbin.com/otakaw/7/edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [$watch is triggered directly after init, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875105/watch-is-triggered-directly-after-init-why)

Comment: see the section http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch and you will find your answer

Comment: Thanks, really it's documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

The listener is called only when the value from the current
`watchExpression` and the previous call to `watchExpression` are not
equal (**with the exception of the initial run**, see below).

After a watcher is registered with the scope, the **listener fn is
called asynchronously** (via `$evalAsync`) to initialize the watcher.
**In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of `watchExpression` didn't change**. To detect this
scenario within the listener `fn`, **you can compare the `newVal` and
`oldVal`. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was
called due to initialization.**